# Button to open a modal with jtable data read from a webservice

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

i have an html page that uses jtable to fetch data from a webservice, lets say that this page is on the url ../hr/test.htm so my page looks like this

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
   <head>
   <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>        
    <link href="../css/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>            
    <link href="../css/jtable-themes/lightcolor/red/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />        
    <script src="../js/jquery.PrintArea.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.ui.datepicker-el.js"></script> 
    <script src="../js/jquery.myfunctions.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">       
  $(document).ready(function () {  
  $(document).myfunctions({});
  $(document).myfunctions('initialize');   
  var hrUrl = $(document).myfunctions('hrUrl');
  $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
    title: 'Test with Persons',
    actions: {
     listAction: hrUrl + '/getRemainingLeaves'
    },
    fields: {
        leaveCategoryDesc: {
            title: 'Category',
            width: '8.3%'
        },
        leaveRemaining: {
            title: 'Remaining',
            width: '8.3%'
             },
        approvalfrom: {
            title: 'from',
            width: '8.3%'
             },
        approvalto: {
            title: 'to',
            width: '8.3%'
      }
    }
  });
  $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');
 });
 </script> 
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="PersonTableContainer"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

then on a second page i want to have a button image that when the user click on it a modal will populate using jquery **that will show the above page inside the modal**... is this possible?? lets say the image is on ../images/adies.png  how can i d this?? i have tried many different ways with no lack so far.. any help would be really appreciated..

thank you guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u r awesome for your answer!! really thank you for that,, so in case anyone need it i managed to do it with modal and iframe that is in my new page in the head i put smthng like this,

```
  $(document).ready(function () {        
   $(".test").click(function () {
    $("#thedialog").attr('src', $(this).attr("href"));
    $("#somediv").dialog({
        width: 730,
        height: 230,
        modal: true,
        close: function () {
            $("#thedialog").attr('src', "about:blank");
        }
    });
    return false;
 });
```

and in the body i call it like that,

```
   <a href="../hr/test.htm" class="test" ><img src="../images/adies.png" id="right-button" alt="Left Leaves" title="Left Leaves" align="right" style="width:40px;height:40px"></a><br>
   <div id="somediv" title="Left Leaves" style="display:none;">
   <iframe id="thedialog" width="700" height="150" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

once again thank you... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can load the content of a page in a modal. Ther's how I do this

```
function openDialog(dialogSelector, titleStr, url, options) {
    $(dialogSelector).attr('title', titleStr);
    if (url != null && url != "") {
        $(dialogSelector + "Content").load(url, function() {
            $(dialogSelector).dialog(options);
        });
    }
 };
```

In my dom :

```
<div id="dialog1" style="display: none">
    <div id="dialogContent"></div>
    <div id="dialogFooter"></div>
</div>
```

and how I use it :

```
var options = {
    ...,
    modal : true,
    ...
};
$("...").click(function(){
    openDialog("dialog1", "hey", ".../my/action", options);
});
```